# Bison grammar rule to match a group of tokens

Tags: c, bison

Is there a way to match multiple tokens at once? Right now one of my rules looks like this:

```
rule:
    T_A { $$ = some_common_behavior(); }
  | T_B { $$ = some_common_behavior(); }
  | T_C { $$ = some_common_behavior(); }
  ... // many more tokens
```

But it would be far more maintainable if a group of tokens could be matched at once:

```
rule:
  T_A | T_B | T_C | ... { $$ = some_common_behavior(); }
```

PS: the `some_common_behavior` call already handles current token, hence there is no need to repeat code for each token like in the first example. I just need a better way to declare this without all the repetition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you just group the `T_*`s into an expression and then use that expression in your `rule`?

```
rule:
   Ts { $$ = some_common_behaviour(); }
;

Ts:
  T_A
  | T_B
  | T_C
  | ...;
```

Comment: Worked as expected for me. Not that I'd do it all the time but this fits the specific case. Thanks.